# is there a proper way to do function/method calls in programming

Tags: coding-style

So, I was coding and I essentially got this line of code

> return parseInt(trim(elem.value.substring(1, elem.value.length)))

And I was thinking, is this proper or would a professor/employer slam me for allowing such a line of code.

I feel like, while nice a tidy, this is difficult to understand what the crap I was doing at first glance. This one isn't so bad b/c most of the calls are common enough (making sure it's an int, trimming the string so conversion works and removing unnecessary information from the beginning of the string)

But, is this ok? Or should I break it down and comment each line so it's easier to understand for future programmers?
Like...

```
var returnInt;
returnInt = elem.value.substring(1, elem.value.length); //remove $ symbol
returnInt = trim(returnInt); //trim whitespace
returnInt = parseInt(returnInt); //convert to int
return returnInt;
```

I wasn't sure how to search for this so I apologize if there's something on this.

Comment: there's no right/wrong. either style has points for/against them, and it comes down to personal preference, or the preferences of your coding team.

Comment: Agree with Marc B with the caveat that if you are doing something unusual, uncommon, or complex, the more verbose style would be appropriate.  For simple, common uses the single-line approach is clear, concise and perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first format is fine, except that it can make runtime exceptions like NullPointerExceptions difficult to debug (because the stack trace returns a line number and there are multiple things it could be on one line). So if NPEs can occur, write it out in multiple lines.

And it's not necessary to end-of-line comment every line. It's pretty obvious what trim and parseToInt do to anyone but the most novice programmer, and a simple Google search would turn that up anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay as long as you format your code nicely. e.g. your line may look like:

```
return parseInt(
         trim(
           elem.value.substring(1, elem.value.length)))
```

quote:

> Or should I break it down and comment each line so it's easier to understand for future programmers? Like...

```
var returnInt;
returnInt = elem.value.substring(1, elem.value.length); //remove $ symbol
returnInt = trim(returnInt); //trim whitespace
returnInt = parseInt(returnInt); //convert to int
return returnInt;
```

It's not easier. Excessive mutability is evil; and this won't work if your values have different type. (Oops, you are probably using dynamic-typed language, but then the name of var `returnInt` will be misleading, because at some program states is is indeed not an `Int`). Please, don't write code like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't care about what professors or employers would think about it. Unless it becomes really really long, I always inline such simple statements as they are more understandable and clear that way.

I think it looks more complicated when you break it down. And I hate useless assingments and equals signs. I only break  statements when I do something really really complicated and it needs comments for other people and for me in the future.

In your example, all of the statements are pretty simple and clear. None of them needs comments or explanations to an average developer.